# try and catch with a prepared statement

Tags: php, try-catch, prepared-statement

I have had a very hard time with this query and it was suggested to me to learn try and catch blocks to more easily figure out what is wrong. So this is my first attempt at it.

I am getting the error for my @stmt2 not being defined for my `print_r($stmt2)` line.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: stmt2
```

This is my attempt at the try catch. Am I doing anything wrong with it for this error to come up?

```
try {
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    throw new Exception("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );

//Prepare
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id`=? AND `id`=? LIMIT 1")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $cid, $tid);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

      /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception($con->error);
    }
}
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numrows == 1){
    echo "<table width='100%'>";
    if ( $_SESSION['user'] ) { 
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onclick=\"window.location = 
    'forum_post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."$tid=".$tid."'\"> <hr />";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td></tr>";
    }

/*} 
catch (Exception $e)
{
    //print_r($e);
    echo "There has been an error with the $stmt block.";
}

print_r($stmt);

try {*/
    foreach($stmt as $row) {

        //Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum posts
        if($stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?")) {
        //var_dump($stmt2);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "ii", $cid, $tid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
        }   
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
                <div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />
                by ".$row2['post_creator']." - " .$row2['post_date']. "<hr />" . $row2['post_content'] ."</div></td>
                <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
            }
    }       
    }   else {
        echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
        }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    //print_r($e);
    echo "There has been an error with the foreach $stmt2 block.";
}
print_r($stmt2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna track all the errors that happen in your code, you can use *try, catch* statements to handle them in proper way. Inside try block, you can put all your code or part of it. If something fails, it will generate an **exception**.

That exception also can be thrown by yourself using the next statement:

```
throw new Exception("I think something's failing");
```

Just after *try* block, you have to declare the *catch* block which will handle the **exception**, making it available to you. In the following example I will print the error message.

```
<?php

try {
    /* all your code */
} catch (Exception $e) {
   /* if something fails inside try block will be catched here */
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

You can find more about this here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Well I want to know if I am doing the try/catch correctly and why I am getting the error that my `$stmt2` variable is not defined.

Comment: You're getting the error about your $stmt2 variable because it's hardcoded in your catch statement. Using $e->getMessage() will handle the first exception who makes you out of the normal flow of the script.

Comment: Could you explain that further or show me what you mean? Still trying to learn try/catch.

Comment: Would it be best to have two try blocks in my case and are you saying I'm getting my error because I'm trying to print my $stmt2 outside of the catch? I thought the print $stmt2 was the finally part?

Comment: You can have too much try blocks as you want, also you can nest them. It's your call. If you check the link I've put in my answer, you'll notice there's also a "finally" block. Finally block will be executed always, with or without error. Catch block will be executed only if there's an exception.